# Should you capitalise "eBay" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do you capitalize a proper noun such as “iPhone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)

Which is correct?

> On the internet you can buy stuff. **eBay** is one place where you can buy stuff.
>
> On the internet you can buy stuff. **EBay** is one place where you can buy stuff.